horror movie about a woman escaping from multiple serial killers
A girl who is working at a car dealership is kidnapped and driven to a field.  Another serial killer then kills the original kidnapper with a sniper rifle and ties the kidnapped girl to a pillar.
The girl escapes, somehow killing the person with the sniper rifle.  However, she runs into another person that tries to kill her, escaping by killing him in an underground tunnel.
At the end of the movie it's shown that there are real events that the movie is based on and twelve skeletons were found in a field.

Country: American, live action
Genre: Horror
Year : After 2000 and in color

Asking two questions in one is usually frowned upon in the community. Try separating each movie into a different question and giving as much detail as you can. Aproximate year, if the movie had colors or was in black and white, any actors that you remember, any particular memorable scenes?

i dont want fill up the forum with questions so i make one and i try give as many info remember...if i know the actors or year probably i be able to find these movies by myself

It's a Q&A forum, filling it up with (ideally good-quality) questions is what it's for :)

I'm just giving you the guidelines which are commonly passed on. I gave you everything I remember. But this isn't a forum. The mods wish to have the questions separated so each of them may have an appropriate answer. Maybe someone has one of your answers, but he won't be able to answer both. So you won't get any of them.

ok i will make 2 questions

ok i just found this movie ....Carnage Park

You might want to add that as a proper full answer.

@papias Good! If it reopens, you may post your answer. :)

how i can do this?can you do this?i mean answear to my post

@papias You can't, while its On Hold. Gotta wait to be reopened.
